# Vue 3 ref Proxy unaccessible

Tags: axios, proxy, vuejs3, ref

I am trying to get data from an API and want to reuse it inside my script. I am using a ref to store the data. Usually i can access my data via myRef.value. But i do observe some behaviour that makes it complicated to access my data inside the proxy.

This is my request inside a composable.

```
export default function (url) {
  const data = ref([]);
  const count = ref(0);
  const page = ref(1);
  const isLoaded = ref(false);
  const getUrl = computed(() => {
    if (page.value > 1) {
      return `${url}?page=${page.value}`;
    } else return url;
  });

  watchEffect(async () => {
    axios({
      url: getUrl.value
    })
      .then((res) => {
        data.value = res.data.results;
        count.value = res.data.count;
        isLoaded.value = true;
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  });

  const updatePage = (newPage) => {
    page.value = newPage;
  };

  return {
    data: data,
    count,
    page,
    updatePage
  };
}
```

The output of those 2 logs is the following:
[image: output of the 2 console.log()]

So what is happening here? I assigned red.data.results to data.value. But logging those 2 gives different results. Accessing a ref's .value should return the proxy's content, but here we see a proxy again.

I do find workarounds, but i would like to understand before i avoid this.

Comment: Looks like `data.value` is an array, so you probably should check `data.value[0].id` no?

Comment: I updated the question, since that was just a typo. The basic question remains.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `data` variable is not a ref, but a Proxy, most likely because you ran it through `reactive()`. When you access the data again, Vue wraps it into a Proxy to keep reactivity:

```js
const { reactive, toRaw } = Vue;

const data = reactive({})
const arr = [{id: 1}, {id:2}]
data.value = arr
console.log('`data.value === arr`:', data.value === arr)
console.log('`toRaw(data.value) === arr` :', toRaw(data.value) === arr)
console.log('prints the array in the snippet console, check browser console', data.value)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Comment: I pasted the complete function to show, that i am not setting it to a reactive. Maybe vue does internally, but then thats exactly the part i want to understand.

Comment: @haligh Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem